# Dynamic imageview with text iphone

Tags: iphone, image-processing

In my UIView.I need to show dynamic images i have an array size not fixed.
i will loop through the array.
and i want to show two image ( Both images are known 1.png and 2.png  )
and want to show text over that images.

i tried with CGRectmake but need help :(

Please Anyone can suggest anything ? any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

Just place 2 `UIImageView`s and 2 `UILabel`s into your view, and then set the properties accordingly:

```
UIImage *image1 = [yourArray objectAtIndex:x];
UIImage *image2 = [yourArray objectAtIndex:y];
yourImageView1.image = image1;
yourImageView2.image = image2;

yourLabel1.text = @"text one";
yourLabel2.text = @"text two";
```

Comment: What if i dont know the array length ?

Comment: `[yourArray count]` gives you this knowledge. :)